# Can a time stored as 4 digits be formatted with gmdate in PHP?

Tags: php

I have some times stored in the format 1100, e.g. 1100 is 11am.

Is there a way to use the time stored in that format to change the formatting?

e.g.

```
$time = '1100';
echo gmdate( 'H:i', strtotime( $time ) ); // This formats it nicely, but I'm expecting it to output 11:00 but it returns 09:00
```

Comment: Check you timezone in php. [timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)

Comment: If you know for sure you have HHMM then why even bother with date parsing, just cut the string in half and insert a colon. `[$hour, $minute] = str_split($time, 2); echo "$hour:$minute";` or maybe `echo substr($time, 0, 2) . ':' . substr($time, 2, 2);`

Comment: If you don't want timezones to affect the time and just format and show it, you can use date instead of gmdate

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question (use `gmdate()` to format a time with not date component):

```
$time = '1100';
echo gmdate('H:i', strtotime("$time UTC"));
```

But there's no reason to have calendar involved here:

```
$time = '1100';
echo mb_substr($time, 0, 2) . ':' . mb_substr($time, 2);
```